# simple automatic railway gate control using arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i've done one simple arduino project. since i'm a beginner in arduino, i couldn't find the bug in my codes. can anyone help me to solve my problem. i'm planning to keep one ir sensor which detects the train and motor closes the gate after a time delay motor rotate in other direction and opens the gate.

```
int s;
int Sensor=3;
int leftMotor = 12;
int rightMotor = 13;

void setup(){
  pinMode(leftMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Sensor, INPUT); 
  }

void loop(){  
  s = digitalRead (Sensor);


  if( s == HIGH ){
    digitalWrite (leftMotor, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (rightmotor, LOW);

    delay(10000); 
    digitalWrite (leftmotor, LOW);
    digitalWrite (rightmotor, HIGH);
    delay(10000);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: digitalRead doesn't debounce the input if it is noisy.

Comment: @stark there is no need for debounce, since there is a 10 seconds delay. hari, what kind of motors are you using? and what kind of sensor?

Comment: i'm using normal dc motor and an IR sensor.